# Select ul with x number of children

Tags: jquery

I have the next structure: ul > li > ul > (x number of li). My question is, how I can select elements with only: ul > li > ul > (3 or less li). That is because I need do some actions only in this elements. I have that, but... you know, I'm nove in Jquery :´(

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

var hideElement = $(".show-more-option")
    if($('.content').length<=3){               
        $hideElement.switchClass(".show-more", "hide-more");        
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using jQuery's [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```js
$(function() {
  let threeOrFewer = $("ul").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("li").length <= 3;
  });
  threeOrFewer.addClass("switchClass");
});
```

```css
.switchClass {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

The function called countListItems takes a ul as a function argument and counts the number of li children that it contains and looks to see if that number is less than or equal to 3. If so, it adds a class to the ul, 'threeOrLess'.

All that class does is add a background color of green to the ul that matches your criteria. This allows you to distinguish between the number of li's in a given ul. Once you're correctly identifying the ul's you want based on your criteria, you can specifically target just those ul's to style them or make them behave however you want.

Notice that there are 2 ul's in the sample markup and we are running our function countListItems against both of them. The first ul, with a class of 'foo', has 3 li children, so we have a match and want to target this ul. The second (the ul with a class of 'bar'), however, contains more than 3 li children so we don't do anything to that ul.

https://jsbin.com/neradafice/edit?html,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
           ul.threeOrLess {
               background-color: green;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                1
                <ul class="foo">
                    <li>a</li>
                    <li>b</li>
                    <li>c</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                1
                <ul class="bar">
                    <li>a</li>
                    <li>b</li>
                    <li>c</li>
                    <li>d</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                countListItems($('.foo'));
                countListItems($('.bar'));
            });

            function countListItems(ul) {
                if ( ul.children('li').length <= 3 ) {
                    ul.addClass('threeOrLess')
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```